# How do we improve the signal to noise ratio?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting

I'm admittedly relatively new to Writing.se. However one thing I have noticed is that unlike other stack site there are a lot more opinion based questions that generate lots of answer of varying value. One example (and inspriation for this question) is [How do I avoid the "chosen hero" feeling?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42422/how-do-i-avoid-the-chosen-hero-feeling).

To me this is an excellent question and something that a high quality answer from our experts would be very useful for. However it currently has 14 answers, most of which only add one or two points and are far from a comprehensive response.

There are other questions which demonstrate this pattern but the specifics don't really matter. In general our good questions generate *more* answers rather than  *better* answers.

What I don't want is to discourage new participants or to reduce our answered question percentage. Community discussion on this site is great and I don't want to hurt that. But we have a [history of low votes](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1208/can-writers-graduate-correlation-between-voting-and-progressing?noredirect=1&lq=1) and that make it difficult for the great answers to rise to the top.

**What can we do to increase the signal to noise ratio on our popular questions?**

Comment: I don't have a problem with there being multiple answers that touch on only a few points.  In a place like, say, Worldbuilding, the questions are often more technical and there are right and wrong answers.  Writing can have that too (and WB can have more opinion type questions that aren't closed) but most of our questions are more subjective and things that would take a book to explain in full.

Comment: Is your problem with the questions, or the answers?

Comment: @wetcircuit My issue is with the amount that a reader would have to shift through to find the good information in the answers. The question is great but there are lots of answers that only provide a small amount of value. If we had more voting happening the good answers would rise to the top and this would be less of an issue. At the moment I worry that users will miss the best answers as they are hidden among lots of okay answers.

Comment: Also I will admit, voting has since mostly handled this issue on the linked question. If that is a trend we can keep up, I'm happy with that.